# concatenate four columns that have few Null values in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have four string columns `feed1,feed2, feed3, feed4` which have 30 % of `NULL` values and the requirement is to concatenate four columns with a comma. When I used `CONCAT_WS`  it is giving numbers instead of string values and it is showing `,,,` if all the columns are `NULL` instead of `NULL`. Please let me know how to do handle the `NULL` values and concatenate four columns into one column.

Thanks,
Madhu

Comment: use CONCAT(IFNULL(fieldname,""),",") etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IFNULL` function like below,

```
select CONCAT_WS(',',IFNULL(feed1,'NULL'),IFNULL(feed2,'NULL'),IFNULL(feed3,'NULL'),IFNULL(feed4,'NULL')) as 'value' from TABLE;
```

To learn more on `IFNULL` click [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_ifnull.asp).

Comment: Please accept the answer if that suffice your expectation.